# Como manter o login ativo Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Estou com algumas dificuldades em conseguir manter o login ativo na minha app, seja por email ou por conta google. Já tentei pelo método do SharedPreferences mas não obtive muito sucesso.

Este é o código do botão do login:

```
DefaultButton(
        text: "Continuar",
        press: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            _formKey.currentState.save();
            try {
              KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context);
              UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email,
                  password: password);               
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil( 
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Tabs()),  
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
              if (e.code == 'user-not-found') { 
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: "Nenhum usuário encontrado para esse e-mail.");
                print('Nenhum usuário encontrado para esse e-mail.');
              } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                Fluttertoast.showToast( 
                    msg: "Senha errada fornecida para esse usuário.");
                print('Senha errada fornecida para esse usuário.');
              }
            }
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

O Firebase Auth permite que você se inscreva em tempo real nesse estado por meio de um Stream . Uma vez chamado, o fluxo fornece um evento imediato do estado de autenticação atual do usuário e, em seguida, fornece eventos subsequentes sempre que o estado de autenticação for alterado.

Existem três métodos para ouvir as alterações do estado de autenticação:

**authStateChanges()**

Para assinar essas alterações, chame o método authStateChanges() em sua instância do FirebaseAuth:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Os eventos são acionados quando ocorre o seguinte:

- Logo após o ouvinte ter sido registrado.
- Quando um usuário está conectado.
- Quando o usuário atual é desconectado.

**idTokenChanges()**

Para assinar essas alterações, chame o método idTokenChanges() em sua instância do FirebaseAuth:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .idTokenChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Os eventos são acionados quando ocorre o seguinte:

- Logo após o ouvinte ter sido registrado.
- Quando um usuário está conectado.
- Quando o usuário atual é desconectado.
- Quando há uma alteração no token do usuário atual.

**userChanges()**

Para assinar essas alterações, chame o método userChanges() em sua instância do FirebaseAuth:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .userChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Os eventos são acionados quando ocorre o seguinte:

- Logo após o ouvinte ter sido registrado.
- Quando um usuário está conectado.
- Quando o usuário atual é desconectado.
- Quando há uma alteração no token do usuário atual.
  Quando os seguintes métodos fornecidos por FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser são chamados:
- reload()
- unlink()
- updateEmail()
- updatePassword()
- updatePhoneNumber()
- updateProfile()

**Estado de autenticação persistente**
Os SDKs do Firebase para todas as plataformas oferecem suporte pronto para uso para garantir que o estado de autenticação do usuário seja mantido nas reinicializações do aplicativo ou nos recarregamentos de página.

Em plataformas nativas, como Android e iOS, esse comportamento não é configurável e o estado de autenticação do usuário será mantido no dispositivo entre as reinicializações do aplicativo. O usuário pode limpar os dados armazenados em cache dos aplicativos usando as configurações do dispositivo, o que limpará qualquer estado existente armazenado.